# Disable Scrolling in Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a carousel slider on the bottom of my website. Now that slider goes to the left and to the right when i scroll into that slider. I want to disable that. Know anyone how i can disable this feature?

http://www.be-virtual.org/schnittchen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open file jquery.contencarousel.js and comment out (or remove it) following part of code:

```
// adds events to the mouse
                    $el.bind('mousewheel.contentcarousel', function(e, delta) {
                        if(delta > 0) {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( -1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        else {
                            if( cache.isAnimating ) return false;
                            cache.isAnimating   = true;
                            aux.navigate( 1, $el, $wrapper, settings, cache );
                        }   
                        return false;
                    });
```

This part of code binds the scrolling by mouse with changing slides in your carousel.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable scrolling, you should be able to just add this to your CSS:

```
 overflow-x: hidden; /* Horizontally */
 overflow-y: hidden; /* Vertically */
 overflow: hidden; /* Both ways */
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery.mousewheel.js > comment the type event "mousewheel"

```
53  //event.type = "mousewheel";
```